# How to fade out current video and fade in new video onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to play a video when I click a button, then have a different video fade in *while* fading out the current video when clicking another button. This needs to be a dynamic transition with the user clicking randomly (ie, from 1 to 3 or vice versa). Here's my current code without any fading:

JS:

```
<script>
video = document.getElementById('video');
source = document.getElementById('source');

window.PlayVideo = function(srcVideo){
video.pause();
source.setAttribute('src', srcVideo);
video.load();
video.play();
}

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<a onclick="PlayVideo('fire.webm');"><button>Play Video 1</button></a>

<a onclick="PlayVideo('smoke.webm');"><button>Play Video 2</button></a>

<a onclick="PlayVideo('merged-rain.webm');"><button>Play Video 3</button></a>

<div id="xxxxxx">

<div>

<video id="video" width="520" height="360" loop muted controls><source id = "source"/></video>

</div>
</div>
```

Example link: http://nov-exl.dx.am/movie%20change.html
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var source = document.getElementById('source');
var timer = void 0;

  window.PlayVideo = async function(srcVideo){      
    source.setAttribute('src', srcVideo);
     fade('out');
     try {
      await video.pause();
      await video.load();
      await video.play();
      fade('in');
    } catch(err) {
      console.log("Promise rejected");
    }

  }

  function fade(opts){
      if(typeof opacityTimer !== 'undefined') clearInterval(opacityTimer);
      var opacity = opts === 'in' ? 0 : 1;
      opacityTimer = setInterval(function() {
      if ((opts === 'in' && opacity >= 1) ||(opts=== 'out' && opacity <=0) ){
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
      opacity =  opts === 'in' ? opacity+(opacity * 0.1 || 0.1) : opacity-(opacity * 0.1 || 0.1);
      video.style.opacity = opacity;
      video.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + opacity * 100 + ")";
    }, 25);    
  }
```

Comment: Just tried out this code in firefox, I don't see any fading - any idea why?

Comment: @novoluz , I am not sure why this happens at your end. I have tested this on Chrome 65.0.3325.146 and Firefox 63.0 , and the fading is being applied to the video on button clicks.

Comment: I tried your code on the latest versions of chrome and firefox, but I'm not seeing the videos fade into each other as they're supposed to. Thanks for your help though.